# Hiding critical data when logging soap requests/responses

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws

**Problem:** I'd like to log every

- soap request
- soap response
- soap fault

on a server side. But essential is to hide part of requests/responses (for example a password field in an authorization request). 
**I'm using Spring + Spring-WS.**

**What I've tried:**

- `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor`. I rejected it because it logs everything.
- own interceptor which unmarshals soap request/response to java object.  I have autogenerated schema so I couldn't use `toString()`. I made own method which makes pretty String and skipps critical information. I used `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder`. Everything's fine but this lib doesn't support collections [sic!]
- I did the same as above but used aspect to intercept soap calls. I gained access to an exception (soap fault) so I could log it easier and prettier than in above case.

**And I didn't try but already rejected:**

- own interceptor behaving like `PayloadLoggingInterceptor` but cutting critical parts before logging (using regular expressions)
- IF cascade

It's not NASA level issue. It's quite basic. I assume 1M people struggled with it earlier. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I don't know if its relevant for you, but you can try audit4j, it has @DeIdentify function which will hide information when logging

Comment: @riso I cant use `@DeIdentify` because it can be used in fields level and I have auto generated classes based on schema. And I can't tell to generator to mark some fields with `@DeIdentify`. But thanks - I didn't know audit4j. It can be useful in other cases.

Comment: I thought you have some implementation where you have request as input for method, then you could parse this request and log with @DeIdentify like public void saveCreditCardId(@DeIdentify(left=5) int cardId)